# Inconsistency in sql query output using OR after WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a query on a complex db:

```
SELECT *
FROM
table1,
table2,
table3,
table4,
table5,
table6,
table7,
table8
WHERE
a = b and
c = d and
e = d and
(
(strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW' AND x = g) 
OR (strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX' AND y = g)
)    and
f = h and
i = j
```

Only works when **strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX'** and not when **strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW'**. When I replace

```
(
(strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW' AND x = g) 
OR (strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX' AND y = g)
)    and
```

with either **x = g and** or **y = g and** it works fine in two seperate queries runs like that. The error message for the case **strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW'** is:

***ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation***

Before this error message comes the computer goes into deep thought for I guess 2 minutes.

What am I doing wrong here?

f.y.i. I looked at the names of the fields of the of the two seperate runs and they appear idendical. I mean the scema of the output looks the same for both. But I'm not 100% sure they are the same, if that matters i.e.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please explicit JOIN clause so, you can understand better in which part of your query you go in CROSS JOIN. Another advice, put the table name before your field

Comment: `deep thought` = server is executing the request. Logical error in the query (unintended cartesian product comes in mind) might force the server to do a lot more work than necessary. `user requested cancel of current operation` here means that timeout has expired, which is probably set to 120 seconds. As others have said try to rewrite the query using proper join syntax. Most likely this will reveal mistake in original query.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm such a noob. How would I use join in the context of my query?

Answer (score 4):

When `strfldvar = 'BROKEN_ARROW' AND x = g` (or if `strfldvar` is not `BROKEN_ARROW` *or* `BROKEN_BOX`), the `y = g` part is not evaluated, which seems to be causing the query to run for longer than you expect - until it's eventually killed by you, your client or resource limits. I suspect that's the only join condition for whichever table `y` is from, so you end up with a cartesian product.

When `strfldvar = 'BROKEN_BOX'` then both `x = g` and `y = g` will be evaluated, so you wouldn't get the same cartesian product, against either of the tables providing `x` and `y`.

If you are essentially deciding which table to include in the query based on that flag then you'll need to redesign this; possibly with a union of two queries, one which joins to `x` and the other on `y`; or with separate queries and you decide which to run; or maybe even with outer joins. But it depends on what you're really trying to do and what the data looks like. The code you have shown is a too generic to guess what will be appropriate.